# Compare new/changed file sizes from one point in time to another

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-space

My problem is that I cannot find out where my disk space is being utilized after freeing space; for example I free 20GiB, then three days later it's used up despite me not downloading or transferring any files in that time.

I have attempted to use WizTree (WinDirStat alternative), though it's only really useful for looking at the disk as a whole, where 20GiB can easily go missing.

Is there some way in Windows (or some software) that can allow me to take a snapshot of all the file paths and their filesize on the disk at a particular time, and compare it to an earlier snapshot, then show me the difference in new/changed files, effectively allowing me to determine where my disk space is going?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots otherwise we can’t really help you.

Comment: There are simple ways to record all files and folders and their size and store these in a text file or table that don't require any extra software, just some simple batch coding. I'm pretty sure I answered a question about getting file and folder info like this several years ago here. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out WizTree can export and import CSV files, and importing works just as well for a differential CSV than an ordinary CSV.

I developed a program to create a differential CSV from a past and future CSV from WizTree, which can then be loaded back in WizTree

Source code and download available here: https://github.com/AlphaDelta/WizTreeCompare

Comment: That's awesome, but it seems WizTree cannot show deleted files, so the diff is only in one direction (added and updated files, not deleted)?

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek I've updated my program to optionally output a full differential, [WizTreeCompare v0.3.0-rc.1](https://github.com/AlphaDelta/WizTreeCompare/releases/tag/v0.3.0-rc.1), I haven't tested it thoroughly so you might hit some bugs. You're correct - it seems WizTree doesn't support negative file sizes (it does an unchecked cast from a `long` to `ulong` resulting in petabyte file sizes) and no combination of flags seems to be able to reflect a deleted file, so the full differential is not compatible with WizTree but it might be useful.

Comment: thanks for the update and details. Have you tried contacting WizTree to add such support?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect some Windows' updates files being sneakly downloaded to your PC. But 20 GiB seems too much even for than.

It looks like you've used Windows' stock "system cleaner", please give us a screenshot of it before you wipe everything out.

Try to use your Windows completely offline and see if space is still wasted. And by offline I mean physically offline (no ethernet cable or WiFi hardware connected).

It also looks like your 20GiB of file are small ones and scattered, but there may be only one or little processes who make all these files. Windows' "Performance Monitor" may give you a clue about processes that heavily writes or use a lot of I/O... or even CPU. I'd look for that first too.

Also, have you enabled file-system level compression or anything that happens at the filesystem level ?

Comment: "I would suspect some Windows' updates files being sneakly downloaded to your PC" I too expected something like this, so I tried "Disk Cleanup" which refuses to delete the Windows update files (hangs at the last notch of progress bar indefinitely, only 8GiB anyway). No system or file compression used. Funnily enough I actually made a program to do what I was looking for anyway (comparing two disk/MFT snapshots) after I made the question.

Comment: "Funnily enough I actually made a program to do what I was looking for anyway". Well I'm also looking for that, can you share that please ?

Comment: I've posted my solution, be aware it requires WizTree

Answer (score 0):

**Option1:**
I found this utility: [TreeMapFs/FilePro](https://www.saleensoftware.com/TreeMapFs).
It is free for personal use.

The utility promises to do the job (an excerpt from the manufacturer's website):

> ▪ Save entire or partial volume snapshots
>
> ▪ Compare snapshot against current disk state or past snapshots
>
> - Examine changes by difference in size or percentage difference

The GUI is far from pretty and scanning is rather slow, but it works.

I've done two scans of C:, created snapshots and launched "Compare Snapshots" command.

It is clearly visible in this example that pagefile.sys is 2GB bigger than before.
[image: TreeMapFs compare snapshots]

**Option2:**
If you do not shut down your computer, you can simply run any disk usage analyzation program, leave it open, run another instance later and visually compare results.

In this way, you can track what got bigger over time:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[SizeTrend](https://www.dimastr.com/sizetrend) (I am its author) can be an option: it lets you save a snapshot of a scan, and compare it with a current scan at a later point:
[image]